# What does "Unknown type dependencies" mean when preloading PHP scripts?

Tags: php, preloading, php-7.4

I'm attempting to make use of the new [preloading feature](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/preload) available since PHP 7.4.

I ran `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` to generate a list of all available classes in the project, and used the following `preload.php` script to preload them:

```php
$files = require 'vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php';

foreach (array_unique($files) as $file) {
    opcache_compile_file($file);
}
```

And configured this preload script in my `opcache.ini` file:

```
opcache.preload=/path/to/preload.php
```

And restarted `php-fpm`. Now `systemctl status php-fpm.service` reports the following warnings:

> PHP Warning:  Can't preload unlinked class Brick\Money\Context\CashContext: Unknown type dependencies in ... on line 16
>   PHP Warning:  Can't preload unlinked class Brick\Money\Context\AutoContext: Unknown type dependencies in ... on line 17
>   PHP Warning:  Can't preload unlinked class Brick\Math\BigRational: Unknown type dependencies in ... on line 17
>   PHP Warning:  Can't preload unlinked class Brick\Math\BigInteger: Unknown type dependencies in ... on line 20
>   PHP Warning:  Can't preload unlinked class Brick\Math\BigDecimal: Unknown type dependencies in ... on line 15

**What does "Unknown type dependencies" mean**? How can I get these classes preloaded?

*Note: I'm the maintainer of the offending libraries [Brick\Math](https://github.com/brick/math) and [Brick\Money](https://github.com/brick/money), so if these are in need of modifications to make them preloadable, I'm all ears!*

Comment: The RFC mentions this: *Only classes without unresolved parent, interfaces, traits and constant values may be preloaded.* This means there are files containing types (classes, interfaces, traits) that you have to preload *before* the ones mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: What OS is it? .

Comment: @Kubo2 I'm not sure whether they have to be preloaded *before*: what about circular dependencies? I would expect them to work in any order, but I may be wrong. Anyway, I've had other warnings related to classes that were not included in the preloading script, but these were different, they said "Unknown parent" when a class attempted to extend a non-preloaded class. This one says "Unknown type dependencies", and I'm trying to find out what this means.

Comment: @revo It's CentOS 7.7, does that make any difference?

Comment: To avoid dependency issues, you can preload using `require` instead of `opcache_compile_file()`. This will handle circular dependencies fine, but will hard error if preloading fails (instead of just warning).

Comment: @NikiC I somehow expected the PHP files to be just *compiled to opcodes* during the execution of the preload script, and the linking to be done **after** the script has ended, and all necessary classes have been preloaded; this would prevent any dependency issue. Isn't this the case? Does the order matter?

Comment: That is how it basically works. The caveat is that a class can only be preloaded IFF its dependencies can be preloaded. When opcache_compile_file() is used, this needs to be proven a priori, which is quite hard. Circular dependencies are not supported in this mode right now. When require is used, this is checked a posteriori instead, which is easy and has no issues with circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It means that PHP couldn't find a class in a preloaded file at runtime. [This only happens when there might be methods that are incompatible](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/b250f89b92541e7c60310152cda6a50f0fa30225):

> **Preloading: Relax known type restrictions**
>   Check whether there is a parent/interface/trait method with the same name and only then require the type to be known. This reduces the number of cases where this triggers in practice a lot.

Preloaded files don't use the Composer autoloader, so classes that don't get preloaded won't exist.

Symfony fixed this by [creating a `Preloader` class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/32032) that can load its dependencies. This is [how to use it](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34089#issuecomment-552191678) to preload `LoaderInterface` and `AnnotationClassLoder`:

```
<?php 
// preload.php
$classes[] = 'Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface';
$classes[] = 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationClassLoader';

Preloader::preload($classes);
```

Until there's a better way to do it, you can copy that class or preload all classes that the library depends on.

---

If you can allow preloading failures to be hard errors, use the [answer from NikiC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59520529/3150271#comment105213683_59520529):

> To avoid dependency issues, you can preload using `require` instead of `opcache_compile_file()`. This will handle circular dependencies fine, but will hard error if preloading fails (instead of just warning).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still can't figure out what's wrong with the offending classes, though. Take for example [CashContext.php on line 16](https://github.com/brick/money/blob/d86bf7f36599bd9e9228221c5e8f10a509d49fa3/src/Context/CashContext.php#L16), it's just a class implementing an interface **in the same package**.

Comment: @Benjamin The error could be better but I think `BigNumber` is the problem there. PHP is still not very good at handling covariance and contravariance in preloaded files.

Comment: So you mean that any class accepting or returning `BigNumber` in any of its methods could potentially not be preloaded?

Comment: @Benjamin Yes. There are some times when PHP can figure it out by comparing the full class name strings but it isn't doing that here. It could be because `BigNumber` is `abstract` or another overload exists somewhere else. Preloading is still new so it should get better.

Comment: @Rain Yes, preloading can cause a hard error when you use `require`. But that should mean that there's an actual error. NikiC helped a lot with the [preloading pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3538) so he knows what he's talking about.